# Android deep link always opening in the Browser first and then the correct activity

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, android-5.0-lollipop, deep-linking

On Android version 5.0 we are using Deep links since App links work only from Android 6.0 onwards. We are facing an issue on these devices: when the intent is launched from the Host app first the link is opening in the Browser and then after brief delay (2-3 seconds) it launches the target app even though we select the “Always Open in app” option. Is there anything we could do to open the link directly in the app without opening in the browser briefly?

```
    <activity android:name=".deeplinking.DeepLinkingNavigationActivity">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999”>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https"
            android:host="@string/deep_linking_host"
            android:pathPrefix="/authorize/" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: If the app is not installed then the Browser needs to handle it hence we need http/https scheme. When it asks which app to open for the first time it is showing "Browser" and "Our app" correctly. But even after selecting our app with "Always" every time it opens the browser first and then the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you answered yourself correctly - the way to deep link in Android in version 5.0 is via URI schemes or Intents, and both require a browser redirect to do that. Therefore you'll have an intermediate browser that is opened (and cannot be avoided).

Pay attention that different browser will require different deep linking behaviour (URI Schemes, Intent, or even no support for deep linking at all).

Comment: Please can you forward me if there is any official documentation about this?

Comment: Using URI Scheme will require you to execute some `location.href=myapp://` that is executed from browser, so you need to open a browser for that.

Also many apps have in-app browsers, so they handle links by first open the browser and then do the redirection.

Comment: I didn't understand the solution exactly. I am facing the same error. Can't we do something to skip the activity to be launched in the host app.